# why react-router automatically go back to previous route on dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an old app that want to add react-router to it. Specifically I'm using `HashRouter`. The app also use `redux` and `react-redux`, but no other middlewares like saga or thunk.

The app has several tabs, each on mount will call `loadData` to fetch from backend. When I'm in tab#1 and try to navigate to tab#2, the `loadData` method for #2 is called. But upon calling `dispatch`, the page automatically goes back to tab#1. The data is loading, and when it's loaded (all dispatch has been called), I try to nav to tab#2 and this time it's successful.

I cannot understand why. Looks like every time `dispatch` is called, the router will revert the window location to previous one. Could anyone please give me a hint on how to solve it?

simplified code:

tab#1 and tab#2 both have similar structure

```
function tab1(props){
const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(()=>{
  if(!initialized){
    loadData();
    setInitialized(true);
  }
}, [initialized])

function loadData(){
  // if data already in store, exit function early.
  // otherwise:
  dispatch({type: 'REQUEST_DATA'});
  // fetch backend
  // after receive json, dispatch
  dispatch({type:'RECEIVE_DATA', data: json});
}

return (
 // return
)

}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { HashRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import * as reducers from "./reducers";
import createPersistedState from './createPersistedState';
...

let middlewares = [];
if (!window.production) {
  middlewares = [logger]
}

const reducer = combineReducers({ ...reducers });

const persistedState = createPersistedState();

const store = createStore(reducer, persistedState, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

...

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
          <div id="root-container">
            <HashRouter>
              <ErrorBoundary >
               <Header />
               <div className="app-wrapper">
                 <Switch>
                   <Route path='/tab1' component={tab1}/>
                   <Route path='/tab2' component={tab2}/>
                 </Switch>
               </div>
               <Footer />
             </ErrorBoundary>
           </HashRouter>
          </div>
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("app")
  );
};
```

reducers/index.js

```
export {default as reducer1} from './reducer1'
export {default as reducer2} from './reducer2'
export {default as reducer3} from './reducer3'
export {default as reducer4} from './reducer4'
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your reducer?

Comment: @AdrianPascu thanks I edited the index.js above. I didn't change anything the original reducer for the routing.

Comment: @AdrianPascu I found the cause, it is on reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok turns out not a problem with react-router nor redux, but a old reducer I overlooked to update. In that reducer, window.location.hash is by default reset. That explained everything -- every dispatch will trigger that reducer. After remove that, everything works as expected.